# Changing hex color of a graphic

Tags: adobe-photoshop, hex

[image]

I have this graphic. I need to change the color of the graphic to hex color: 1485cc...is there a way to make this graphic match that particular hex color hue...without me having to have to re create the graphic.

Comment: Besides using replace color, you can use a HUE/Saturation adjustment layer and eyeball it but for best results you will want to re-create the graphic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is another approach with the result shown below:

1. Add a Solid Color adjustment layer above the image, enter the HEX color you want in the field as shown
2. Change the blend mode of this layer to "Color" and you are done.
3. I am adding this step based on EricP's comment and my reply to him. If you change the blend mode to Hue, you will eliminate the Luminosity and Saturation components and work only with Hue. You can also adjust the tonality by adding a curves layer if necessary.

Below are screen captures and the final image to show the result.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are welcome @StanleyVM, simple is better for me. Let Photoshop do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @ACEkin  Yes, simple solution and probably the first way I would've gone.  The only issue i have with doing this way is that it usually produces a lighter color then what was intended. Of-course it all depends on how accurate you need to be.  If this solution works for Stanley VM the I'll delete me post as to not confuse.

Comment: @ErickP, switching from Color to Hue blend mode may yield slightly darker appearance by removing the "brightness" component of "Color" behind. Another way of dealing with that may be to add a curves layer, change blend mode to Luminosity and adjust until the desired tonality is achieved. I don't think you should delete your answer, that is certainly another way of doing it.

Comment: sadly this trick does not work with transparency

Answer (score 4):

**You can also:**

1. Convert your image to grayscale mode
2. Use the levels to make your black density at 100% 
   (Menu Image > Adjustments > Levels) and then select the black color picker and then use it to click on the music note (e.g. the color at 100%).

[image]

3. Finally, go in the image > mode > duotone, select Monotone and insert your Hex color. Then convert back to RGB color mode.

[image]

Alternative (less precise than duotone though):

You can do step 1 and 2, convert back to RGB color mode, and then add a blue layer filled with your Hex color, and set that layer to Screen on top of your image.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly with transparency, except I had to change my output levels in step 2 from `0 255` to `0 0`