# Change only one color to a specific hex color in an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to change color in graphic image to a specific hex color. I found this solution here [Changing hex color of a graphic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65562/changing-hex-color-of-a-graphic) but this changes colors in all of the graphic. I just want to change the color that is inside the text **Boaters**

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the same effect that was mentioned in the previous answer

**You just have to specifically select the 'Boaters' color**

Select > Color Range > choose the Boaters color using eye drop > Set Fuzziness to 200%

If there are areas that will get selected other than the colors within the 'Boaters' then just deselect using your wand tool

[image]

2. Follow the steps in the previous tutorial

Use a solid color then select the hex you wish to use.

[image]