# Change color of details in photo to a specific color in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-conversion

I want to change the color of details in a photo eg. make a green sweatshirt into a read sweatshirt (to the company profile color).

**Today I am:**

1. Masking out the part I want to change (or using Select > color range)
2. Change the color by using "Color Balance"

What I would like is to in step 2 be able to provide the color I am trying to match and have Photoshop making the color balance automaticly. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing hex color of a graphic](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65562/changing-hex-color-of-a-graphic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new layer, fill it with the target color. Hide it.
Duplicate your artwork layer (in order to always keep the original).
Select your newly created copy, then select Image > Adjustments > Match Color.
Finally select your target layer (orange in the example below).
This is fast and easy, but not perfect, adjustments are usually required (especially contrast)

[image]

**Edit:** In addition, I must say that I tried to answer your question about "matching" a given color, but that I don't like this feature because results are often unsatisfying.
Here's another workaround (CMYK mode required):

1. Make a copy of your original layout. Desaturate it to maximum. Purpose is to avoid background color to go through mask.
2. Create your mask from the original using color range with high tolerance.
3. Make another copy of original layout. Open curves panel and remove C, M and Y, just keep the black curve. This layer will be used for keeping contrast. Put it on top and apply multiplying.
4. Finally, select the mask layer, get selection from mask and fill it with the desired color.

Result should be quite realistic:
[image]