# Changing the hue of an image

Tags: color, transparency

I have very little experience with image manipulation. This is probably a very simple procedure, but I have no idea how to do it.

I have an image that I want to use, and it's perfect for my intentions except for the color. How do I change the color (hue) of this image without touching anything else like the size or transparent background?

[image: button hover blue]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing hex color of a graphic](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65562/changing-hex-color-of-a-graphic)

Answer (score 3):

Use an image editor, such as GIMP or Photoshop.

In GIMP click File > Open, open the PNG image. Click Colours > Hue-Saturation. Adjust the hue slider. Then File > Export As, give your file a new name and end with the file extension .png - then hit Export.

In Photoshop click File > Open, open the PNG image. Click Image > Adjustments > Hue/Saturation. Adjust the hue slider. Then File > Save As, give your file a new name, then hit Save.

Answer (score 0):

If you use photoshop then you can try this simple and nice solution.

Open the file, then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and a popup will come up where you can slide to change color.

Set as you wish and save back with desired extension.