# Change Hex Color of Graphic Image in Photoshop With Transparent Background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, vector, color-conversion

My question is very similar to this one:

[Changing hex color of a graphic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65562/changing-hex-color-of-a-graphic)

I just want to change the hex color of the shell graphic from #53767F to #375459:

[image]

According to the [top answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65562/changing-hex-color-of-a-graphic) in that question, I need to add a solid color adjustment layer above the image and enter the hex color that I want in the field.

That's what I'm trying to do - I'm adding a solid color adjustment layer by doing:

Layer > New Fill Layer, and choose an option - Solid Color, Gradient, or Pattern. Name the layer, set layer options, and click OK.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Well, this seems to change the *background* to the color that I'm looking for, but not the actual color of the shell graphic. What am I doing wrong here? The blend mode was set to color, as was suggested. I also tried changing the blend mode to hue, but it didn't seem to make a difference. The background is still there. I just want to make the shell graphic a darker green - #375459 - and preserve the transparent background.

Answer (score 2):

If your pattern (I mean your artwork) is non-transparent, I think you just need blending mode *Normal* only. Then you can add a solid color layer (#375459) and use it as a clipping mask. You should get what you need.

[image]

What you're doing wrong: I think the problem is just blend mode you've set.

You can also use *Layer > Layer Style > Blending Options > Color Overlay*.

(Since I didn't have original PNG image, I just used quick selection tool to remove background just to explain).

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach, is to just click the 'fx' icon at the bottom and select 'color overlay':

[image]

and select the new hex color of the color overlay here:

[image]